# Reposting to other websites from my own

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm creating a wordpress website, and I want that when I or an user make a post it gets automatically reposted to other sites.

I know that there is API for major websites, for example facebook and twitter. But what if I want to make a post in olx.com? they have no API. Is there a way to create a php function that logs into olx, post and logs out? It doesn't have to be a php function, i'm open to ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of reasons to not do that.

Better stay safe and play with the websites that have api, allow feeds or already implemented a way for you to post on their sites.